Boot into black screen with fix by switch to tty and back
I am running Ubuntu 22.04， with NVIDIA driver 555.42.
Everytime I startup will have a black screen with no signal. The fix could be
Ctrl + Alt+ 4 switch to TTY4 then Ctrl + Alt + 1 switch back.
What could be the reason? How do I fix this?
